# Our edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes.

Tags: bug, support, status-completed

While trying to make a good faith edit, I'm often greeted with:

> Our edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes

I've never seen this on any of the other Stack Exchange sites. Sadly I don't have the necessary reputation here to help out.

My two-part question:

1. Is this known to the local moderators?
2. How many edits fit in the edit queue?

Answer (score 2):

It is now known ...

We were returning the wrong error message.

We have a special case where we totally disallow suggested edits from child meta sites (like this one) but the check was deferred a bit.

I just fixed this, so you should not see this message anymore unless the queue is really full (it fits 20) and has never filled up for the photo site.